# Make a URL available only from within application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say, I have a URL to edit a post **.../posts/1/edit**

I don't want this URL to navigate to a link when a user pastes it on his browser. However, if I have a link to this URL from within my application, the application should route to this URL.

Is it possible to achieve something like that?

I have no authentication system in the application.

I am just looking to see if there is an elegant solution to it. Else, I am sure I can find ways around. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `request.referer` to get the page the user is coming from. This should allow you to achieve what you want. Note that this is not 100% reliable, sometimes the referer header might not be set. But in most cases it will work.

Alternatively, you can set a session variable that indicates whether the user is allowed (or not) to open a page (set a session variable on the main page with `session[:allowed] = true`, check its presence on the hidden page). When the user does not have a session variable set, render error or redirect to the main page (something like `render :status=>403 and return unless session[:allowed]`).

Comment: I ended up implementing the inelegant solution. This is what I did.     if session[:allow_post_edit]
  session.delete :allow_post_edit
  ...my variables... 
else
  redirect_to show_path(@var)
  return
end

Answer (score 1):

One of the easy ways would be send a unique header with the GET request and in the edit page, make sure you verify this header and only if it is present go ahead else throw a 401.

Ofcourse to make it much simpler, send a unique argument like /posts/1/edit?application="not-browser-1234"

and in edit page

if $_GET[application] != "not-browser-1234"
   exit

Comment: Well, that would work. But I have a link to that page, and if the user see that the link is /posts/1/edit?application="not-browser-1234, he could paste that in the browser address bar instead of /posts/1/edit and it would take him to the page. I want to avoid that. Thanks.

Comment: Well then sending the headers would be the best way, or as someone else suggested, you can use request.referer. However since you are writing the application, you can hide the link and have a button which on click would call a javascript function that would go to the link and attach application="not-browser-1234". And ofcourse you can always hide the js part

Comment: well, I think that would be too much trouble for such a simple problem. I just used a session variable. I was only looking to see if more elegant solutions existed. Thanks a lot though.